# Can a Divine Crusader that have more domains choose different spells of the same level from different domains?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, domains, divine

Can a Divine Crusader that have more domains choose different spells of the same level from different domains?

For example: if I have 3 level one slots and I have the domains of Strength and Protection, can I choose to prepare two Enlarge person and one Sanctuary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.

The divine crusader specifically prepares spells—which is almost pointless for the typical divine crusader, as they only have one spell of each level. They could have metamagic feats that make the preparation non-trivial, but they aren’t really expected to. Or they could get more spells, e.g. through an extra domain. *Complete Divine*—the same source as the divine crusader itself—details how extra domains work, making it very likely that this interaction was anticipated by the authors. And those details say someone who can prepare spells (but isn’t a cleric) can choose to prepare spells from the extra domain in any slot (of sufficient level, of course).

Comment: Can you please write the page of the English version of the "Complete Divine" manual where you found this information? I cannot find it, Thanks.

Comment: @Fanaval Which information? The statement that a divine crusader prepares spells is on page 34, the information on handling extra domains is on page 20.